# Make react-bootstrap Alert invisible initially

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alert, react-bootstrap

I am using versions:

```
react@16.8.6
react-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.8
```

I am trying to create an alert that is initially invisible.  [According to the documentation, the show attribute is the right one to use, but it doesn't seem to be working.](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/alerts/)

These are the things I have tried, but none have work:

```
<Alert variant="danger" show="false">Passwords must match</Alert>
<Alert variant="danger" defaultShow="false">Passwords must match</Alert>
<Alert variant="danger" show=false>Passwords must match</Alert>
<Alert variant="danger" defaultShow=false>Passwords must match</Alert>
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a string for `false`. Use a javascript false with braces instead:

```
<Alert variant="danger" show={false}>Passwords must match</Alert>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to modify the show from a string to a boolean just like this

```
<Alert variant="danger" show={false}>Passwords must match</Alert>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using false as a string but the show attribute accepts a boolean value. use

```
show={false}
```

Instead of

`show="false"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attribute in state, so, if you change the state, you force your app to re render, and the alert will be displayed

```js
<Alert variant="danger" show={this.state.show}>Passwords must match</Alert>
```

Comment: Thanks - this will be my next step since the alert will be shown in certain circumstances.  I wanted to get the "easy" part done before introducing anything more complex.

Comment: IMO, this is the best way to show an alert or toast, as the app will re-render if state changes. Another opcion but more complex if you are going to work with props, is use componentWillReceiveProps (to modify the state there) o shouldComponentUpdate (to check if you want to re-render or not, comparing nextprops and nextstate with their current values)